# Clone multiple repositories into common parent folder structure

Tags: windows, git, github

My issue is that I have a client, let's call them 'Evil Corp', that provides my company with lots of business through various projects, which we use GitHub repos for. Let's take 2 and call them 'TotallyNotPolluting' and 'CoveringUpPolluting'.

I would like for my employees to be able to clone the 'TotallyNotPolluting' repo into a folder 'EvilCorp' by default when cloning.

## Behaviour:

So the starting structure is:

```
E:
└── Work
    └── Repos
```

1. Have starting folder structure: `E:\Work\Repos` to start
2. In Git Bash/GitHub Desktop/whatever clone the repo 'TotallyNotPolluting' (selected location is the starting folder structure `E:\Work\Repos`)
3. Have ending folder structure: `E:\Work\Repos\EvilCorp\TotallyNotPolluting`
4. In Git Bash/GitHub Desktop/whatever clone the repo 'CoveringUpPolluting' (selected location is the starting folder structure `E:\Work\Repos`)
5. Have ending folder structure: `E:\Work\Repos\EvilCorp\CoveringUpPolluting`

So the final structure is:

```
E:
└── Work
    └── Repos
        └── EvilCorp
            ├── TotallyNotPolluting
            └── CoveringUpPolluting
```

This way, all the repos are organized into client folders without employees taking extra steps to do so.

Is this possible? To have the Clone action create then clone into (if one doesn't exist) or clone into (if one does) a parent directory?

**NOTE:** I have looked into using Submodules, but I don't want a repository "EvilCorp" that contains other repositories. I just want the folder when cloning.

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question, but if you create a top repo "Evil Corp" and create sub folders into it and then add projects to individual folders, then people will have to always clone "Evil Corp" repo and they will end up getting all other sub projects. However, keeping multiple un-related projects in one single repo is not recommended. Please correct, if I understood something wrong.

Comment: @prabodhprakash I added a **NOTE** at the bottom of the question that having a repo 'EvilCorp' that contains other repos is not what I want. I just want a folder to be created and *then* cloned into, or if the folder already exists clone directly into it.

Comment: You can write a script to do it for you. A simple shell script that goes to parent folder and check for individual folders, if exists, check for repo in that folder - clone the repo, if nothing is present. If the sub folder is not present, if first creates the sub folder and then clone the repo. Thus you can have multiple different repos on github and an executable shell script that manages them all on client side.

Comment: @prabodhprakash how would I do this on clone automatically? Is there a way to inject a shell script into the Git process for cloning? If you know how, submit it as an answer and I'll accept it if it works.

Comment: On mobile right now, will send script as first thing in morning. What will the script do - create a parent folder (e.g e:\\work\\repos) and then will create individual sub folders and within each sub folder will clone a repo. If folder/subfolder/repo is present, it will skip. Also, I use mac, so you'll have to make adjustments to make it work in Windows. Are the expectations right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a script like below. I've not tested it properly but this should give you the right direction to move it. The purpose of this shell script is to create a parent directory and then individually create each sub-folder, check if sub-folder is empty. If empty, clone the repo. This shell script can be distributed to employees as an executable then, when run, will clone repos into right places.

```
#create the directory, if it does not exist

directoryName="<your directory name here>"
mkdir -p directoryName
repos="TotallyNotPolluting CoveringUpPolluting"
forwardSlash="/"
#go into directory
pushd $directoryName



for repo in $repos; do

    #check if directory is not present, if true, create the directory

    [ ! -d $repo ] && mkdir -p $repo

    #go into directory

    currentDirectory=$directoryName$forwardSlash$repo
    if [ "$(ls -A $currentDirectory)" ]; then

     echo "directory is not empty, skipping to clone"
    else
        pushd $directoryName$forwardSlash$repo
        git clone "git@$codeHost:$codeUser/$repo.git"
    fi

done
```

Comment: It's not *exactly* what I'm looking for, but it's close enough I suppose.
Ideally, the solution would be a script run when a clone is made, not a clone made when the script is run. That's why I was asking about injecting the script to run on repo clone command.

Selected as answer, since it appears to not really be possible.

Comment: You may consider marking it as correct answer, if this points you to absolutely correct path to your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have a super project just containing submodules (if you really want git to know - it does not work well though in my experience).

Instead have a super project containing just a "check everything out" script which the user can then run which gives whatever repositories you want to be present.